# WPF Databinding is not showing the value of a private property of a WPF Form

Tags: c#, wpf

I've spent hours on this. I have read documentation on Databinding and done a lot of research. I've been pointed to a few other similar questions but whilst they have given me some pointers, none of them seem to help fix my specific use case.  THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE! I do not want to implement the full M-V-MV architecture for a simple form showing a few properties for an object I pass over to a window. I do want to use databinding I would appreciate if someone could just point out what exactly I'm doing wrong.

I am trying to get databinding working using a WPF window with a simple Object stored as a property of the Windows Class.

I have a Class called Car with a Property called Make (i.e. VW, Audi etc).

```cs
    public class Car : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private string _make;
        public string Make
        {
            get => _make;
            set
            {
                _make = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public Car()
        { Make = "Empty";}
    }
```

In the XAML of the WPF form I have a Text box set to bind to Make

```cs
<TextBox Text="{Binding Make}"/>
```

In the Codebehind of the WPF form the windows constructor and the Car Property is

```cs
public WindowCarDetails()
{
// instantiate the private property that contains the class.
//  An empty car has "Empty" as its make
_car = new Car();
InitializeComponent();
this.DataContext = _car;
}

private Car _car;
public Car Car
{
get => _car;
set
    {
    _car = value;
    }
}
```

In a previous window, I instantiate the Window and pass a car to the Car Property of the Window.  I  have checked and this does pass over the Car details successfully

```cs
WindowCarDetails CarDetails = new();
CarDetails.Car = (Car)CarDataGrid.CurrentItem ;
```

When I test this, I find that the text field does have "Empty" as its value, so its picking up the default value of the empty Car instance I create.   However, it should show the Make of the Car instance being passed to the Window.

I have tried removing the _car=New Car(); line and then the text box is just blank.

However, if I make the the Car Class part of the window it does work but I do not want to do this as it mixes the the window with generation of classes!

Can someone show me why the code does not show the value of the _cars Make property.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Car` property in WindowCarDetails is redundant. Remove it and simply write the following constructor

```
public WindowCarDetails()
{
    DataContext = new Car();
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

and an assignment like this:

```
WindowCarDetails carDetails = new();
carDetails.DataContext = CarDataGrid.CurrentItem;
```

---

If for whatever reason you need to keep that property, its setter must obviously update the DataContext:

```
public Car Car
{
    get => _car;
    set
    {
        _car = value;
        DataContext = _car;
    }
}
```

Also note that `Car` is a *public property*, not a *private property*.

Comment: Thanks @Clemens. Thats an interesting way of setting the DataContext which I can use elsewhere.  However, I do need to pass a Car Object over, as the datagrid window is not the only window that calls the CarDetails window.  This is why Car is a Public Property.  So fixing this in the code is putting the DataContext in the Car Properties setter.  If I have it in the setter is there a need to have it in the WindowCarDetails Constructor?  Thanks

Comment: As said, the Car property is redundant. You can always assign a Car instance directly to the DataContext (as you can see in the answer). However, if you keep the property as shown, you can of course write `Car = new Car();` in the constructor.

Comment: I need to use the _car instance variable and the Car Property as I need to do futher processing on the passed object dependant on other settings. I tried typing that into my original comment but it timed out on me. I've not shown that to keep the focus down to the issue.   Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can always cast the DataContext like `var car = (Car)DataContext;`